# Nativescript (TS) - readTextSync alter data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

Under Nativescript (Ts), i read a csv file, extract here :

```
25300-2-0842;A PATTE PEINT;2;PC;2 10 C;;;;;
25300-2-0845;A PATTE PEINT;2;PC;2 10 C;;;;;
25300-2-0980;B FIXATION BATTERIE PEINT;2;PC;2 10 C;;;;;
25300-2-1390;B TOLE PEINT C3;8;PC;3 10 C;;;;;
25300-2-1528;A CAPOT PEINT C3;4;PC;4 10 C;;;;;
25300-2-0285;B TOLE PEINT;4;PC;2 11 C;;;;;
```

I need the location of an item, location is the 5th token of a line and it's read with

```
global.currentLine.emplacement = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], 5).trim().toUpperCase();
```

When i parse lines, the value of the location token is altered

Trace shows that :

- CSV file contains "2 10 C"
- fileInput[i] returns "25300-2-0842;A PATTE PEINT;2;PC;210 C;;;;;"
- therefore getToken returns "210 C"
- and then location is incorect

Any idea ?
Does the readTextSync make implicit conversion ?

```
export function getToken(Text:string="", Index:number=1, Separator:string=";"):string {
  let result = "";
  if ((Text != null) && (Text != "")) {
    let temp = Text.split(Separator);
    Index--;
    if (Index < temp.length)
      result = temp[Index];
  }
  return result;
}

async function loadData():Promise<boolean> {      
  global.lignes  = -1;
  const filepath = fileCheck("stock.csv");
  if (filepath == "") {
    helper.loading.hide();
    await helper.dialogsModule.alert({
      title        : "Erreur critique !",
      message      : "\nLe fichier des données stocks (stock.csv) n'est pas présent.\nL'application EASY va se terminer.",
      okButtonText : " OK ",
      cancelable   : false
    })
    exit()
  }
  const filefevcsv : File = File.fromPath(filepath);
  global.fileinput = filefevcsv.readTextSync(loadError, encoding.UTF_8);
  let dummy      = "";
  let fileInput  = global.fileinput.split("\n");
  let lengthData = fileInput.length;
  if (lengthData < 3) {
    helper.loading.hide();
    await helper.dialogsModule.alert({
      title        : "Erreur critique !",
      message      : "\nLe fichier des données stocks (stock.csv) ne semble pas complet.\nL'application EASY va se terminer.",
      okButtonText : " OK ",
      cancelable   : false
    })
    exit()
  }  
  global.lignes      = 0;
  global.data.length = 0;
  let maxloop        = lengthData + 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < maxloop; i++) {
    dummy = helper.getToken(fileInput[i],1).trim();
    if (dummy == "")
      continue;
    global.lignes++;
    global.currentLine.reference   = dummy;
    global.currentLine.description = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], 2).trim();
    global.currentLine.quantite    = parseCheck(helper.getToken(fileInput[i], 3).replace(",", "."));
    global.currentLine.unite       = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], 4).trim().toUpperCase();
    if (global.currentLine.unite == "")
      global.currentLine.unite = "PC";
    global.currentLine.emplacement = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], 5).trim().toUpperCase();
    // Structure différente si gestion double emplacement ou non
    let colnum;
    if (global.dblempl) {
      global.currentLine.emplacement2 = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], 6).trim().toUpperCase();
      colnum = 7;
    }  
    else
      colnum = 6;
    global.currentLine.observation = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], colnum).trim();
    global.currentLine.observation = global.currentLine.observation.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
    global.currentLine.operation   = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], colnum+1).trim();
    global.currentLine.operateur   = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], colnum+2).trim();
    global.currentLine.horodatage  = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], colnum+3).trim();
    if (global.currentLine.horodatage == "") {
      global.currentLine.horodatage = "--/--/----";
    }  
    dummy                          = helper.getToken(fileInput[i], colnum+4).trim().toUpperCase();
    global.currentLine.cq          = (dummy == "1") || (dummy == "VRAI") || (dummy == "TRUE") || (dummy == "X")
    await global.data.push(helper.copyArray(global.currentLine));
  }
  return true;
}
```

The good result should be "2 10 C" not "210 C"

This alteration is on every line

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I ran:

```
function getToken(
  Text: string = "",
  Index: number = 1,
  Separator: string = ";"
): string {
  let result = "";
  if (Text != null && Text != "") {
    let temp = Text.split(Separator);
    Index--;
    if (Index < temp.length) result = temp[Index];
  }
  return result;
}


function userCode() {
    const str = knownFolders
      .currentApp()
      .getFile("assets/test.csv")
      .readTextSync(() => {}, encoding.UTF_8);
    const splitted = str.split("\n");
    let lignes = 0;
    let currentLine: any = {};
    for (const line of splitted) {
      let dummy = getToken(line, 1);
      if (!dummy) {
        continue;
      }

      currentLine.reference = dummy;
      currentLine.description = getToken(line, 2).trim();
      // currentLine.quantite = parseCheck(
      //   getToken(line, 3).replace(",", ".")
      // );
      currentLine.unite = getToken(line, 4).trim().toUpperCase();
      if (currentLine.unite == "") currentLine.unite = "PC";
      currentLine.emplacement = getToken(line, 5).trim().toUpperCase();
      // Structure différente si gestion double emplacement ou non
      let colnum;
      if (global.dblempl) {
        currentLine.emplacement2 = getToken(line, 6).trim().toUpperCase();
        colnum = 7;
      } else colnum = 6;
      currentLine.observation = getToken(line, colnum).trim();
      currentLine.observation = currentLine.observation.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
      currentLine.operation = getToken(line, colnum + 1).trim();
      currentLine.operateur = getToken(line, colnum + 2).trim();
      currentLine.horodatage = getToken(line, colnum + 3).trim();
      if (currentLine.horodatage == "") {
        currentLine.horodatage = "--/--/----";
      }
      dummy = getToken(line, colnum + 4)
        .trim()
        .toUpperCase();
      currentLine.cq =
        dummy == "1" || dummy == "VRAI" || dummy == "TRUE" || dummy == "X";
      console.log(line, currentLine);
    }
}
```

I got all the outputs correctly:

```
  JS: 25300-2-0842;A PATTE PEINT;2;PC;2 10 C;;;;; {
  JS:   "reference": "25300-2-0842",
  JS:   "description": "A PATTE PEINT",
  JS:   "unite": "PC",
  JS:   "emplacement": "2 10 C",
  JS:   "observation": "",
  JS:   "operation": "",
  JS:   "operateur": "",
  JS:   "horodatage": "--/--/----",
  JS:   "cq": false
  JS: }
  JS: 25300-2-0845;A PATTE PEINT;2;PC;2 10 C;;;;; {
  JS:   "reference": "25300-2-0845",
  JS:   "description": "A PATTE PEINT",
  JS:   "unite": "PC",
  JS:   "emplacement": "2 10 C",
  JS:   "observation": "",
  JS:   "operation": "",
  JS:   "operateur": "",
  JS:   "horodatage": "--/--/----",
  JS:   "cq": false
  JS: }
  JS: 25300-2-0980;B FIXATION BATTERIE PEINT;2;PC;2 10 C;;;;; {
  JS:   "reference": "25300-2-0980",
  JS:   "description": "B FIXATION BATTERIE PEINT",
  JS:   "unite": "PC",
  JS:   "emplacement": "2 10 C",
  JS:   "observation": "",
  JS:   "operation": "",
  JS:   "operateur": "",
  JS:   "horodatage": "--/--/----",
  JS:   "cq": false
  JS: }
  JS: 25300-2-1390;B TOLE PEINT C3;8;PC;3 10 C;;;;; {
  JS:   "reference": "25300-2-1390",
  JS:   "description": "B TOLE PEINT C3",
  JS:   "unite": "PC",
  JS:   "emplacement": "3 10 C",
  JS:   "observation": "",
  JS:   "operation": "",
  JS:   "operateur": "",
  JS:   "horodatage": "--/--/----",
  JS:   "cq": false
  JS: }
  JS: 25300-2-1528;A CAPOT PEINT C3;4;PC;4 10 C;;;;; {
  JS:   "reference": "25300-2-1528",
  JS:   "description": "A CAPOT PEINT C3",
  JS:   "unite": "PC",
  JS:   "emplacement": "4 10 C",
  JS:   "observation": "",
  JS:   "operation": "",
  JS:   "operateur": "",
  JS:   "horodatage": "--/--/----",
  JS:   "cq": false
  JS: }
  JS: 25300-2-0285;B TOLE PEINT;4;PC;2 11 C;;;;; {
  JS:   "reference": "25300-2-0285",
  JS:   "description": "B TOLE PEINT",
  JS:   "unite": "PC",
  JS:   "emplacement": "2 11 C",
  JS:   "observation": "",
  JS:   "operation": "",
  JS:   "operateur": "",
  JS:   "horodatage": "--/--/----",
  JS:   "cq": false
  JS: }
```

Please verify that your csv is correct and doesn't have some other special characters that might be unfluencing the utf8 parse, because the CSV copy/pasted from stackoverflow is working correctly

Comment: Txs @Eduardosperoni , i've triple checked that. Even cleared the app cache.

Answer (score 0):

It was a kind of cache problem.
After doing cache clearing, the problem still exists.
After doing application data clearing, the problem still exist.
After deinstall, shutting down the device, restarting the device and reinstall the app, it works ...

And it's repeatable.
So a kind of cache persisting somewhere about file system ?
The device is a Blackview tab 9.